# Wikitude: Redirecting Orientation Angles

Tags: android, augmented-reality, android-sensors, euler-angles, wikitude

I'm using Wikitude SDK, and I started from "3D Model at Geolocation" using "GeoLocation()" function (instead of RelativeLocation()), in order to visualize a specific 3D model in a specific GPS position.

At this moment, AR registration works using sensors values from the smartphone. 
I need to redirect pitch, roll and yaw values in order to compute my tasks: I obtain telemetry data by a drone, and I need to find a way to redirect the received data into the AR world. Is there a way, also by using android classes and methods or writing more code, to instruct Wikitude about this?

How does GeoLocation use these angles? are these angles read from
variables which can be manipulated elsewhere? Would you give me any
advice?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood exactly what you want to do, but I know that you can't pass any other information than latitude/longitude/altitude to the Wikitude SDK.

Comment: I need to use GeoLocation() to augment the real scene captured by a drone instead of the one coming from the smartphone. So I need to use the six values (positional and angulars) coming from the drone (and the video stream, of course), by injecting these into the application. I know that, until this moment, there are no plans to offer pitch, roll, yaw value passing with a specific function (like setLocation()), but I'm looking for a way to fake the sensor's values by acting on Android... Could someone give me any advice?